# Perl script, how to source an environment variables from .bash_profile

Tags: linux, perl, variables, profile, environment

I need some quick advice on perl script. I created a script that basically calls other perl scripts and many other shell scripts within those. The problem I'm facing, is simply trying to make this run on a universal level by setting one environment variable.

This is on linux RHEL/CentOS by the way...

so I add my variables to .bash_profile and it works without an issue if I MANUALLY source the file first, then run my perl script! This is, OK, but I would like the script to automate this part instead of needing the extra, manual sourcing step.

So my script looks like this... in short

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

`/bin/bash ~/.bash_profile`;

blah blah blah more code etc;
```

When launching the main script (where this part of the code is) it works no problem. It's all the subsequent calls made to other scripts  that are failing...as if it is not passing the variable on to the rest of the scripts.

Any ideas??

Thanks,

Comment: I don't know perl, but I guess it would be relevant to include the code actually calling the other scripts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- The easiest way would be to set the environment variables within perl with `$ENV{"name"}=...`. These variables then will be propagated automatically to any programs started from within the perl script, no matter if perl or shell scripts
- alternatively you could open the .bash_profile, parse it within perl, extract the variables and then set them again within perl with `$ENV`. This is error prone because there might be several ways to declare the variables.
- or you could spawn a shell, which reads the .bash_profile and calls `env` afterwards. Then you read and parse the output from this shell. This is similar to the previous proposal, but the output you have to parse is more clearly defined.
- or you could use a shell script which sources .bash_profile and then spawns the perl script.

Comment: The last options is the easiest one.

Comment: Ok Ill give this a shot... can the $ENV{"name"}= be set similar to scalars and arrays? I mean, can i do something like $ENV{"VARI"}=`/bin/cat ~/.bash_profile | sed 's/VARI=//g'`;

Comment: Not at home where my script is or else id just try instead of asking lol... sorry for my ignorance

Comment: Well, I just created a small script to try it out and no go. Looks like I'll need to come up with an alternative...possibly adding the `. ~/.bash_profile` to the header of each script may be my only solution. 

Thanks for the help guys

Comment: Actually, the easiest way is to test for the necessary members of %ENV being set, and failing that die with a message for the user to configure their account correctly before running your script.

Comment: @NickHatfield: `$ENV{PATH}="/usr/bin:/bin"` etc. The idea of the first proposal was to not use .bash_profile at all, because if you want the perl script the central script to call you can configure it all there. But, if you insist of using a bash profile to configure things for scripts which might not have anything to do with bash at all, the easiest way would then to start everything with a shell script instead of the perl script.

Answer (score 1):

Backticks (and `system`, and `open`, etc.) spawns a separate process that inherits the environment from your Perl program, but can only affect its own environment, not propogate changes back to your Perl script.

[`Shell::GetEnv`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Shell::GetEnv) has a few tricks that will help you incorporate those changes to the child environment, but often times you will find it is easier to parse `.bash_profile` yourself.

---

The more recent [`Env::Modify`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Env::Modify) module can handle this task, leveraging the tricks in `Shell::GetEnv`.

```
use Env::Modify 'source';
source("$ENV{HOME}/.bash_profile");
```

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables are inherited by child processes from their parent, so you simply need to launch `perl` from a shell that sourced `~/.bash_profile`.

`bash` login shells source that file automatically, so it's just a question of setting `bash` as your login shell. You could also use `bash -l`.

```
bash -lc 'exec script.pl args'
```

If you can't setup the correct environment before launching Perl, you can bootstrap a bash login shell.

```
if (@ARGV && $ARGV[0] eq 'setup') {
   shift(@ARGV);
} else {
   exec('bash', '-lc', 'exec "$@"', '-', $^X, $0, 'setup', @ARGV) or die $!;
}
```

In all three cases, the variable is accessed using

```
$ENV{VAR_NAME}
```

Comment: I will have to try this again... ultimately, I just ended up adding the . ~/.bash_profile to the 2nd line of all my scripts and it works as expected now. It's really a dummy proof right... .bash_profile is sourced on login, so this is more so to prevent a "novice" person from having to know how to source the profile, or log out then back in again. The idea is to be able to take the .tar package with my scripts and its subdirectories, and have them work without much intervention...simply adding the variable to .bash_profile and closing the editor

Answer (score 0):

using $ENV we can get any value from .profile/.bash_profile
Example:
suppose any variable is store in your .profile/.bash_profile

export CONNECT="Connection"

Retrieve the same variable in your perl scripts from .profile/.bash_profile as:

my $DB_CONNECT = $ENV{CONNECT};